# What's the meaning of "get something to someone"?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, idioms

I can understand "get something from someone", but am confused about the meaning of "get something to someone".

For example, an excerpt from a NBC interview of Mr. Ron Klain:

> Well, the president-elect had a conversation with Speaker Pelosi and Leader Schumer on Friday and they talked about the need to get urgent action. I mean, we need action during the lame duck. There's a lot of things that are going to have to wait until Joe Biden is president, but this is not one of them. **Getting help to people, getting help to state and local governments**, I mean, it’s not -- obviously, we need urgent help to individuals, but we're going to see layoffs of police, of firefighters, of teachers in the next month in a lot of states and localities unless these local governments get the aid they need.

Another example from: [link](http://globalnation.inquirer.net/95959/ilo-more-job-creation-program-needed-in-yolanda-hit-areas)

> “It’s about **getting livelihoods to people** who have lost everything and doing it the right way to ensure inclusive growth,” Johnson said.

I couldn't locate the usage in any of my dictionaries. Is it an idiom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an idiom, it's just one of the standard uses of the verb **to get**.  If you look up the [get in the dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get), one of the definitions is:

> **3 b :** to obtain and bring where wanted or needed

So in the usage **get something to someone**, it means that you are obtaining something and bringing it to someone who wants or needs it. You can use this definition of **get** with other prepositions as well: "get something from somewhere," "get something for a purpose," etc.

In your first example, the speaker is taking about **obtaining help** (in particular, government money) and **bringing it where it is needed**; that is, to both individual people and to state and local governments.

Comment: You could parse it as “supply something to someone”

Comment: It's funny to say it "parsing" because it sounds mechanical but "to supply" seems like the way how I usually understood "to get something to someone". :)